# I don't know how to do automatic differentiation of a neural network with two outputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, jax

I would like to create a physics-informed neural network (PINN) using JAX.
I have created a neural network with one input (x) and two outputs (y1, y2), how do I differentiate y1 by x and y2 by x?
I know that I can differentiate y by x in a neural network with one input (x) and one output (y) by using the following method, but I do not know how to do it in a NN with two outputs.

```
jax.grad(NN_model)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jax.grad` is designed for differentiating functions that output a single scalar. For more general functions, you may be able to compute what you have in mind using `jax.jacobian`.

Comment: We know we can use jax.jacfwd()  or  jax.jacrev() , but how do we get the value out?

Comment: jax.jacobian is is probably a mistake. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: `jax.jacobian` is equivalent to `jax.jacrev`, and you get the value out by passing inputs to the transformed function, similar to when you use `jax.grad`. If that's unclear, then I'd suggest editing your question to show what you tried.

Comment: `(dy1)/(dx)=jax.jacrev(NN_model)[0]`   
`(dy2)/(dx)=jax.jacrev(NN_model)[1]` 
Does that mean that it will be?

Comment: You need to call your transformed function with some inputs. So it might look like this: `dy1_dx, dy2_dx = jax.jacobian(NN_model)(data)`. If that doesn't help answer your question, I'd suggest editing it to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): it's hard to guess how to solve your problem with such incomplete information.